# como salgo del if y regreso al principio del bucle?

Tags: java, if, while

entra en el bucle while, si ingreso el valor correcto que en este caso es 3, sale del bucle, pero si no, entro al if, y no salgo de ahi aunque ingrese el 3 de nuevo, ¿como hago para salir del if y regresar al principio del while?

```
String velas = "3";
String total ="";

while (total.equals(velas)== false){//aqui empieza el bucle     
    System.out.println("introduce tu respuesta");

    total = S.nextLine();


    if(total.equals(velas)==false){//este if es por si el usuario se equivoca

        System.out.println("respuesta incorreta, ¿quieres una pista? \n pista 1  \n pista 2 \n pista 3 ");



                int opcion = S.nextInt();

                switch(opcion){

                case 1:

                    System.out.println("Tienen que quedar cierta cantidad de velas al final");
                    break;
                case 2:

                    System.out.println("segunda pista");
                    break;

                case 3:

                    System.out.println("tercera pista");
                    break;

                    default:
                        System.out.print("no existe esa opción");


                }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes todo bien a excepcion de un detalle, al usar una nueva linea `\n` y usar `S.nextInt()` unicamente lee y consume el siguiente numero introducido, pero no las nuevas lineas.
Para solucionarlo tengo dos propuestas, una es remplazar

```
total = S.nextLine();
```

por

```
total = S.next();
```

La otra seria consumir el espacio tras leer el numero, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
int opcion = S.nextInt();
S.nextLine();  // <-- Agregar esta linea

switch(opcion){
.........
```

Comment: oh! muchas gracias, funciono a la perfección, aun no entiendo como, pero estudiare la situación hasta entenderla, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Dado que S.nextLine() es string:

```
int opción=0;
Try{ 
opcion = Integer.parseInt(S.nextLine());
}catch(Exception e){}
```

En lugar de:

```
int opcion = S.nextInt();
```

Me basé en la anterior respuesta.

Comment: hola, muchas gracias, probare lo que dices, esta perfecto, de verdad gracias!!!